# Keeping file open while creating two dictionaries from the file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, io

I opened a file and I named it "myfile"; I want to create two different dictionaries from it but the file closes on me and I am assuming because I created the first dictionary in the first loop.
I get an empty dictionary for histogram, I have tried using myfile as x and using x instead of f for the second loop and I get this "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".

Also, I am doing this in a function for a class if that makes a difference.

Does anybody know a way to make this work?

```
    d = {}
    d2 ={}
    with myfile as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            k, v = line.split()
            d[int(k)] = int(v)
            next(f)

        for line in f:
            items = line.split()
            key, values = int(items[0]), items[1:]
            d2.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)


    hist = defaultdict(list)
    for key, values in d2.iteritems():
        hist[len(values)].append(key)
    histogram = dict(hist)
```

Comment: Why do you need two loops? Can't you just loop through `f` once?

Comment: You could set the current position back to beginning of the file using seek().

Answer (score 4):

You're just exhausting the iterator by looping through it the first time. Thus, when you try to loop again, there's nothing left to see.

Just put all your logic in the same loop. I'm not quite sure what your loops are supposed to be doing, but it looks like the first loop as you have it is supposed to apply only to every odd-numbered (0-indexed) line, which is easily accomplished with `enumerate`. The second loop appears to apply to every line, so I'd start with that loop and then add the "first" loop's functionality to it; something like this:

```
with myfile as f: # Better:  with open('/some/file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        # "Second" loop
        items = line.split()
        key, values = int(items[0]), items[1:]
        d2.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)

        # "First" loop
        if i % 2 != 0: # Only process odd-numbered lines
            k, v = items
            d[int(k)] = int(v)
```

Comment: I added, myfile.seek(0) in between my loops and it worked.

I wanted to add an answer to this but I don't have enough reputation so I can't.

Comment: @user2926009 That'll work too, though if your file is big or you're running this a lot you may want to refactor the code to a single loop so it'll run faster.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the question you asked then call `f.seek(0)` after the first loop

However, @henry-keiter 's recommendation to loop over the data only once should be taken seriously.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Henry: don't do the `seek()` unless you really have a need to do a two-pass algorithm.

Is there a reason why you can't?

Also, the use of `next(f)` in the first loop looks suspicious: typically, if you're iterating through something, you do not want to do anything else to that thing backing the iteration.

I was expecting something like the following:

```
with myfile as f:    ## FIXME: this is suspect.  'myfile' is accessible outside this
                     ## `with` already, so there's something weird here. 
    for (index, line) in itertools.izip(itertools.count(), f):
        if index % 2 == 1:
            k, v = line.split()
            d[int(k)] = int(v)

        items = line.split()
        key, values = int(items[0]), items[1:]
        d2.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
```

where you can iterate single-pass over the file.  The first loop in the original code appears to only care about about the odd lines in the file, so this rewrite tries to express that idea.

---

As an aside: the use of `with` here looks off.  We usually do that if we want the `with` to take responsibility over the opening and closing of the resource, and give it a name within the body of the `with`:

```
with open(...) as f:
    ...
```

But the code as written has *already* opened it.  That means the `myfile` variable here was initialized earlier, and is still accessible outside of this `with`.

We'd do more justice to the code if we used a `try`/`finally`, like this:

```
try:
    ...  ## use myfile here instead of f
finally:
    myfile.close()
```

where the code makes clearer that `myfile` will be guaranteed closed at the end of the `try`/`finally`.